# How to take a backup & Restore of Azure SQL table in Azure Blob storage and vice versa

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I want to take an Archival(Backup) of Azure SQL Table to the Azure Blob Storage, I have done the backup in Azure Blob storage using via the Pipeline in CSV file format. And From the Azure Blob Storage, I have restored the data into the Azure SQL Table successfully using the Bulk Insert process.

But now I want to retrieve the data from this CSV file using some kind of filter criteria. Is there any way that I can apply a filter query on Azure Blob storage to retrieve the data?

Is there any other way to take a backup differently and then retrieve the data from Azure Storage?

*My end goal is to take a backup of the Azure SQL table in Azure Storage and retrieve the data directly from Azure Storage with a filter*.

**Note**
*I know that I can take a backup using the SSMS, but that is not a requirement, I want this process through some kind of Pipeline or using the SQL command.*

Comment: To run queries on CSV files in blob storage I suggest you use Databricks or Synapse

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, there is no such filtering option available when restoring the database. But, as you are asking for another way to backup and restoring, SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) is one the most conveniently used platform for almost all SQL Server related activities.

You can use SSMS to access Azure SQL database using server name and Login Password.

Find this [official tutorial from Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tutorial-sql-server-backup-and-restore-to-azure-blob-storage-service?view=sql-server-ver15&tabs=SSMS#back-up-database) about how to take backup of your Azure SQL Database and store it in Storage account and then restore it.

Comment: Yes. I know this but this takes an entire database backup, Can I take a backup of only a single (Selected) table?

Comment: Yes, you can. 
Step 1 : Right click on the database and choose Tasks –> Generate Scripts.
Step 2 : Select the database from which you need to take a backup of the table.
Step 3 :You will see the Table/View options on the screen while scrolling down. Select the table which you want to back up

Comment: Or alternatively, you can copy the specific tables to another database using SSMS and then take the backup of that new database. refer https://www.sqlshack.com/six-different-methods-to-copy-tables-between-databases-in-sql-server/

Comment: I know about the SSMS or manual steps. But I want to automize this process.

Comment: You didn't mention anywhere that you need to automate the process. Please update the question with exact requirements.